# DLL consumes 100 % CPU usage

Tags: com

A particular com dll which i created to do some operations, when loaded in memory it consumes 100% CPU usage.
Because when i rename the dll or unload it CPU usage goes normal state.
How to debug the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Put the .pdb file that you get while compiling that COM .dll into the same folder as the COM .dll, then attach the debugger to the process and pause execution - you will break into the problematic code.

It's crusial to have the .pdb file from exactly the same compilation. Each time you rebuild the .dll you must ensure that you copy the new .pdb file into the location from which the .dll consumer loads it.